# How to run a program on standard input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stdin

I've created an implementation of a Sokoban-solver and the code is currently looking like this (not going to post all the code):

```
public Sokoban() throws Exception{
myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

file = new File("C:/Users/joaki/Desktop/sokoban/readin.txt");
sc = new Scanner(file);
sc.reset();
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    line = sc.nextLine();
```

As you can see I'm just using the filepath to be able to read the file with a scanner, but according to my assignment, it should be looking like:

> To be more concrete if "map1.txt" is a file with a sokoban map your
>   agent program "agent" will get map1.txt sent to in on standard input.
>   Under unix/linux this corresponds to running the program like
>
> `agent < map1.txt`

I don't understand really what they mean, am I supposed to run the program from the command-line argument or from the cmd?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the program reading a file, it should read them from user input - so yes, you should run the program from the command line. This means your program should get the input from `System.in`, not open a file directly:

```
sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Alright, but how do you run it, lets say my class is Sokoban and my file is readin, would it then be:
java Sokoban readin.txt in the command line? and do I have to have the text file in the same map as my prorject?

Answer (score 2):

When creating the `Scanner` use this:

```
sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

It will tell the scanner to read from the default input.